# Caratheodory: Inner Measure

Tags: measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

**Reference**

This problem grew out from: [Inner Measure vs. Outer Measure](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1038696/79762)

---

**Setting**

Given a plain space $\Omega$ and a possibly empty semiring $\mathcal{S}$.

Consider a premeasure $\mu:\mathcal{S}\to\overline{\mathbb{R}}_+$.

Safe a trivial extension:
$$\mu_0(S):=\mu(S):\quad\quad\mu_0(\varnothing):=0\quad(\mathcal{S}_0:=\mathcal{S}\cup\{\varnothing\})$$
*(This accounts the case of an empty semiring.)*

Preextend this to countably disjoint unions:
$$D=\bigsqcup_kS_k:\quad\mu_\infty(D):=\sum_k\mu_0(S_k)\quad(\mathcal{S}_\infty:=\{\ldots,D,\ldots\})$$
*(This overgoes Hahn-Kolmogorov and integrates the induced ring.)*

Introduce the inner measure and outer measure:
$$\mu_+(A):=\inf_{A\subseteq D}\mu_\infty(D)$$
$$\mu_-(A):=\sup_{D\subseteq A}\mu_\infty(D)$$
*(The outer measure only serves for comparison!)*

---

**Problematics**

Now, the problem is that extension is not unique to $\sigma$-algebras:
$$\Omega:=\{1,2\}:\quad\mu_+(\Omega)=\infty\neq1=\mu_-(\Omega)\quad(\mathcal{R}:=\{\varnothing,(1)\})$$
But preferably are finite or leastways countably finite measures.

However, Caratheodory doesn't do that, here!!
$$\mu_+(E_n)<\infty:\quad E_n\nrightarrow\Omega$$

Also this shows that measurability can't be in terms of comparison:
$$E\in\mathcal{M}_\pm:\quad\mu_+(E)=\mu_-(E)$$
*(Therefore, a definition in terms of inner measure itself seems to be the only way out...)*

Imitating measurability for outer measures fails, too:
$$E\in\mathcal{M}_-:\quad\mu_-(A)=\mu_-(A\cap E)+\mu_-(A\cap E^\complement)\quad(A\subseteq\Omega)$$
*(Subadditivity was crucial at alot of steps of Caratheodory.)*

---

**Question**

> So what could be a candidate for measurability in terms of inner measure??

---

**Attempt**

Set an intermediate extension:
$$A\cap S_\Omega=\varnothing,D\in\mathcal{S}_\infty:\quad\mu_\Omega(A\sqcup D):=\mu_\infty(D)+0\quad\left(S_\Omega:=\bigcup_{D\in\mathcal{S}_\infty}D=\bigcup_{S\in\mathcal{S}_0}S\right)$$
Then the extended family contains the space itself:
$$\mathcal{S}_\Omega:=\{\ldots,A\sqcup D,\ldots\}:\quad\Omega\in\mathcal{S}_\Omega$$
*(Caution: This is not a ring anyway.)*